# insert hebrew string to database with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert hebrew strings into a SQL Server database using visual studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2 with connection string but in the database table I get ????? instead of the original string. Just to mentions that it doesn't happen in the past. What could be the problem?

Comment: First of all: are your columns where you store those strings of type `NVARCHAR(x)` ? That's a **must** - those are Unicode columns. Next: how do you **insert** the data? Using ADO.NET and parametrized queries? Some other way? Please show us some code!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change database collation.
Run the following script :

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE YOUR_DATABASE_NAME
COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS ;
GO
```

Comment: sorry but where and how to run it?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio --> New Query --> paste the script --> press "execute"

Comment: can i do it from visual studio?is it modified the database for good?

Comment: Collation change is a significant modification of database. If you are not managing your DB by yourself don't do it - ask DBA. You can read more about collation here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx

Comment: thanks,until now i had no such problem and all the stirgns paste as original.i cant understand why i have this problem now.do you have any idea what was change?

Comment: Like I wrote above, I think the database collation was changed.

Comment: You can also do it by right clikking the DB name in the sql server managemnt studio select properties then select options and there you can select Hebrew_CI_AS collation and save.